# Hibernate Criteria + projection with no results

Tags: hibernate, criteria, projection, hibernate-criteria

I need all distinct people with name <> null:

```
List<Criterion> conditions = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
conditions.add(Restrictions.ne("name", null));
Projection projection = Projections.distinct(Projections.property("name"));
List<People> result = dao.findByCriteria(conditions, projection);
```

where:

```
public List<T> findByCriteria(List<Criterion> list, Projection projection) {

   try {                
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(entityClass);
        if (list != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                criteria.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }
        if (projection != null) {
            criteria.setProjection(projection);
        }
        List result = criteria.list();
        return result;
   } catch (Exception e) {
        // log
   }
}
```

and the generated query is:

```
Hibernate: select distinct this_.name as y0_ from Mrdb this_ where this_.name<>?
```

but I have no results! In fact, using only projection or only a criterion list the query works fine, but using both there is no results.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: looks ok. Did you execute the generated sql manually to see if the results are really coming back?

Comment: @jelies: your answer was correct. You should undelete it.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet! But once posted I thought that was not related to the problem, because the generated query on OP's question seems to be fine.

Comment: The query is fine, but in SQL, like in HQL, comparing something to null will always result to false. To compare with null, `is null` or `is not null` must always be used.

Comment: @JBNizet you're absolutely right. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @joaosavio have you checked the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
conditions.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("name"));
```

the generated query will be something like this:

```
Hibernate: select distinct this_.name as y0_ from Mrdb this_ where this_.name is not null
```

**EDIT:**

As [@JBNizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) said in question's comments:

> The (generated) query is fine, but in SQL, like in HQL, comparing
>   something to null will always result to false. To compare with null,
>   is null or is not null must always be used.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a restriction to the field into ther criteria?

E.g., for the `fieldName` field in your entity:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(entityClass);
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("fieldName"));
```